# Where to start, to develop an online Backgammon game?

Tags: web, javascript, html5, html-canvas

I would like to develop a backgammon game to play against other players online, as a way of learning more Javascript/jQuery and a little game development. I'm a web developer and most of my experience is in PHP. I have minimal Javascript experience and no game development experience. Where should I start? Are there any particular books, tutorials, libraries, or frameworks that would help give me a jumpstart? As a beginner, am I better of using the DOM or Canvas?

Comment: Wouldn't this fall under the 'how do I make game X?' category and therefore be off-topic?

Comment: I don't think so.  At least the final question is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends on how you're planning to render your graphics. Do you want to include animations? A playing board with a pseudo-3d-view?

A top-down view is probably easiest and could be done using DOM and/or Canvas. Since DOM is supported in all major Browsers and jQuery offers a nice toolset (including animations) for DOM manipulation, I'd probably pick DOM over Canvas.

Since this is a multiplayer game, you'll have to think about where to put the game logic. The best approach (which also prevents cheating) would be to keep all the game-logic on the server-side (programmed in PHP) and only have rendering logic and user-input in the clients.

I don't know about any PHP framework that has a focus on game-development. I'd probably pick a multi-purpose framework like [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/), [Cake](http://cakephp.org/), [Sapphire](http://silverstripe.org/sapphire/) or [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/). This will let you focus on the implementation of the game-logic while it will already provide tools for data-persistence or handling of AJAX-request (which you'll probably use for communication).

Answer (score 5):

Since your goal is to experiment with Javascript, I suggest you to take a look on [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) for the server side. It's well suited for what you're trying to do because you can build a realtime server through websocket quite easily and stay DRY. 
Your backgammon logic will be wrote only one time and shared both client and server side (for anti-cheating / game rules validation)

Search for chess games build on these technology.

Answer (score 1):

With the caveats that I have no direct experience with them and their web site login/logout is a bit wonky, I've [heard good things](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/boardgaming-online) about [gamesbyemail.com's developer program](http://gamesbyemail.com/Developers).  They provide a downloadable tutorial for building games within their framework.